# jQuery Syntax & Wordpress Tags

Tags: jquery, wordpress, syntax

I have the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slideSelect').change(function(){
    $('#slideViewer img').attr('src', $(this).val() + '.png');
  });
});
```

I'd like to know how the best way to add a Wordpress Template Tag is to the #slideViewer img section.

The template tag is:

```
<?php bloginfo('template_directory); ?>/builderimages/
```

Basically I want to end with:

```
$('#slideViewer img').attr('src', TEMPLATE TAG HERE + $(this.val() + '.png');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
var IMG_DIR = '<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/builderimages/';

// And then, later on...
$('#slideViewer img').attr('src', IMG_DIR + $(this).val() + '.png');
```

This should work as long as the file with the `var IMG_DIR` part is being processed by PHP/WordPress. If necessary, you could put that in a `<script>` in your template's `<head>` section so that it will be visible everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is client side while php code is server side. So you cannot directly interlink the two. You will need to embed the information somewhere on the page so that it can be retrieved by jquery. You could create any tag you want and then retrieve a value out of it. This is crude, but

```
//server side
<span id="templatesdir" style="display: none;"><?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?></span>

//client side
var templates = $('#templatesdir').html();
$('#slideViewer img').attr('src', templates + $(this.val() + '.png');
```